# Mostrar un registro filtrando por sentencia if con campo bool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, condiciones, filtro, booleano

tengo un index vacio con una caja de texto donde coloco un documento y tengo  que obtener un alumno para matricularlo si es que esta habilitado y un actionlink que me envie a la otra vista con su id. En el caso que no este habilitado tengo que mostrar un mensaje y si no esta en la db ese documento mostrar otro mensaje.
Cuando el alumno esta habilitado lo obtengo y puedo mostrar el actionlink que me envia a la otra pagina. 
El inconveniente es cuando el alumno no esta habilitado o no esta en la db me tira error y no entra a los otros if. 
Osea entra al mismo if que el habilitado y al querer recuperar el id que esta en el actionlink me tira error.

Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' en App_Web_seleccionaralumno.cshtml.ab592015.hpmh7uiu.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Información adicional: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

EL CONTROLADOR

```
public ActionResult SeleccionarAlumno(string Buscar)
    {
        bool esta = false;
        var alumno = from a in db.Alumno select a;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Buscar))
        {
            alumno = alumno.Where(s => s.NumeroDocumento.Contains(Buscar));
            alumno = alumno.Where(h => h.Habilitado.Equals(true));
            if (alumno == null)
            {
                ViewBag.NoRegistrado = "El documento que busca no esta registrado como alumno";
            }    

            if (!alumno.Equals(esta))
            {                    
                ViewBag.Habilitado = true;
                return View(alumno.FirstOrDefault());
            }              

            if (alumno.Equals(esta))
            { 
                ViewBag.NoHabilitado = "El alumno que busca no esta habilitado para matricularse";
                return View();
            }

        }                

        return View();
    }
```

LA VISTA

```
@model GestionIPEM.Models.Alumno

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Alumnos";
 }
<h2><strong>Alumno a matricular</strong></h2>

   @using (Html.BeginForm("SeleccionarAlumno", "Alumno", FormMethod.Get))
  {
<div class="panel-body" style="border:inset">        
    <label>N° Documento:</label>  @Html.TextBox("Buscar", null, new { @onkeypress = "return 
  justNumbers(event);" })
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Buscar" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Limpiar", "SeleccionarAlumno", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
</div>
}
@ViewBag.NoHabilitado
@ViewBag.NoRegistrado
<table class="table table-striped">

<tr>
    <th>            
        Apellido
    </th>
    <th>
        Nombre
    </th>
    <th>
        N° Documento  
    </th>        
    <th>
        Legajo 
    </th>        
    <th></th>
</tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>                
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Apellido)

        </td>
        <td>                
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>                
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento)
        </td>           
        <td>              
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NumeroLegajo)
        </td>
        <td>

            @if (ViewBag.Habilitado == true)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Seleccionar","Create", "Matricula", new { id 
   =Model.AlumnoId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })    
                }          
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>
function justNumbers(evt) {
    var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
    if ((keynum == 8 || keynum == 48))
        return true;
    if (keynum <= 47 || keynum >= 58) return false;
    return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}
</script>
```

Espero alguna ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias observaciones que hacer en tu código:

Para no crear objetos innecesarios, puedes crear el alumno después de checar si el string Buscar viene null o vacío. De una vez podrías verificar que el alumno existe con ese documento.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Buscar))
    {
       var alumnoQuery = from a in db.Alumno select a
                    where a.Documento == Buscar;
     //...
     }
```

Segundo, puedes utilizar FirstOrDefault() para verificar si existe tal alumno con ese número de documento. Este método devolverá un objeto de tipo alumno si cumple con las condiciones establecidas, si no encuentra un alumno, devolverá null. Así podrás verificar más fácilmente. Entonces, lo ideal es que primero busques si el alumno existe. Y luego verificar si está habilitado para matricularse:

Recuerda que

```
var alumnoQuery
```

en este punto no es un alumno, todavía. Es sólo un IQueryable. EntityFramework no sabe todavía si es uno solo, o trae varios que cumplen con la condición. Tendrás que llamar FirstOrDefault para traerlo.

```
var alumnoSeleccionado = alumnoQuery.FirstOrDefault(); 

if (alumnoSeleccionado==null)
  { 
    ViewBag.NoRegistrado = "El documento que busca no esta registrado como alumno";
    return View();
   }
if (alumnoSeleccionado.Habilitado) // esto ya es boolean, no hay necesidad de compararlo con true
    {
       ViewBag.Habilitado = alumnoSeleccionado.Habilitado;
       return View(alumnoSeleccionado);
     }
    else
     {
       ViewBag.NoHabilitado="El alumno que busca no está habilitado para matricularse";
       return View();
    }    
}
```

Espero esto pueda ayudarte.